# 404 on script URL after switching server from Apache to NGINX

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite, url

I have a woocommerce site that runs a script for accounts that has stopped working after moving from Apache to Nginx.

```
example.com/zynk/index.php/wp_posts?select=ID,meta_value&where=post_type....
```

The script gets the parameters using

```
$urlParts = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

This now returns a 404 on Nginx.

I think the following `.htaccess` rules allowed this script to fire on Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I can't get this working on Nginx.

I've tried:

```
location /zynk {
  index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri?;
}
```

However, this does not seem to work.

I could be barking up the wrong tree? or do I just have the rewrite rules wrong?

Comment: You need to implement a location to process PHP - and it needs to accept path info. There is [an example here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) and you may find other examples on Server Fault.